# how to traverse window/view hierarchy of other application in macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, nswindow, app-inspection

I am trying to figure out how to get (read only) entire window/view hierarchy of any application. I get list of all open windows using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`. It also returns window number (`kCGWindowNumber`). It also shows sharing status of root window by `kCGWindowSharingState = 1;`.  Now, I want to check that a particular window/view present in hierarchy of that application. I got `kCGWindowNumber` which is root window of application.

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible via the View Debugging features of Xcode. To use this:

1. Start the target app running as you normally would
2. Launch Xcode, and open a project window (any project, might need to be OS X instead of iOS)
3. Use the Debug > Attach To Process menu once it loads to select your target app
4. Now click the little View Debugging button [image: View Debugging button] or use the menu again: Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy

This should show you a sort of "exploded" view of the app's views as well as a tree of their relationships in Xcode's left pane.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't do this through Core Graphics, since the view hierarchy is entirely a Cocoa concept. You can do this through the [Cocoa Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html), possibly in combination with the GUI Automation support for Accessibility ([here's example code for that](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html)).

Comment: [Here's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) that get's you going. It's actually really easy and powerful.

Comment: Nikolai, you should post that as an answer. And where were you a couple of months ago, when I could have really used this pointer?

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer covers it. I added the link to make it more visible.